# how can i convert javascript+jQuery into reactjs component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i need help how can i convert this code into reactjs component

http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/LNE48/6/

javascript+jQuery code

```
var amount=parseInt($('#amount').val());
var i = parseInt($('#count').val());
var tim;

function run(){
    tim = setInterval(function(){
        if(i>=amount){clearInterval(tim); return;}
        $('#count').val(++i);
    },100);        
}

     
    run();

$('#stopper').click(function(){        
    clearInterval(tim);
});

$('#resetter').click(function(){    
    clearInterval(tim);    
    i=0;
     $('#count').val(i);
});

$('#starter').click(function(){        
 clearInterval(tim);
    run();
});
```

Comment: Why you want to convert this code there is many react app available for the same you will take a look at them it also helps you in conversion
 https://codesandbox.io/s/31rvox7ojm , https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stopwatch , https://jsfiddle.net/vakhtang/j276r2zh/